# Do action upon exit of ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, action, exit, home-button

How can I assign actions on iOS when a user presses the home button (exit)? I want this for an app where uses user a login feature and I want, upon exit, the user to log out. I dont want to use a button for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method,

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

In your application's delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't exit an application programmatically, you can use `exit(1)`, however it's not a good practice, chances are there for your apps to get rejected from Apple.

`applicationDidEnterBackground` will be called for home button press. Try to handle everything here.

Answer (score 1):

Write your actions in `appDelegate`'s "`applicationDidEnterBackground`" method.

Comment: @Andrei Because applicationWillResignActive get called every time app get some specific interruption line phone call, sms. If You want to schedule notification when user press home button and in this case applicationDidEnterBackground is the appropriate place to do this.